# Is it possible to move a <video> element in the DOM without resetting it?

Tags: html, dom

I'd like to create a `<video>` element within my DOM, and then move it to another position without interrupting the playing of that content.

Perhaps more broadly, is it possible to move *any* DOM element without disrupting attached events?

Some approaches include using CSS absolute positioning, but is there a way to actually update the DOM in a way that doesn't interrupt the playback?

Comment: the solutions i've seen have all involved a placeholder element being used with absolute positioning to force the embedded media (`<video>`, `<object>`, etc) to play over top of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The DOM doesn't really have a concept of move, you just have to detach and reattach. As soon as the DOM node is no longer rooted in a document, it loses its playing state.

You may be able to preserve it somewhat by storing it in JS and re-applying it, but that will probably introduce a little skipping.

Comment: Thanks!  Alas, I was trying to avoid this.  Perhaps someday, we'll have support for "move" in the DOM.

Comment: How exactly are you suggesting to store it in a JS. If you could share a snippet it would be of great help.

Comment: @AkshayKasar check out my answer for a code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

As per a workaround, here's the code snippet that worked for me:

```js
function beforeDOMMove() {
   if (video.paused) {
      const currentTime = video.currentTime
      const canPlayListener = () => {
         video.removeEventListener('canplay', canPlayListener)
         video.currentTime = currentTime
         video.play()
      }
      video.addEventListener('canplay', canPlayListener)
   }
}
```